# remote shell for windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, shell

Could recommend a remote shell for windows 7?

Or is there already a remote shell funtionality inside windows 7?

Comment: any reason you cannot use remote desktop?

Comment: @stijn: 1. I have not ever use it; 2. I have no enough bandwith; 3. I prefer shell than desktop environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could enable the Telnet server in Windows, but as Telnet is generally insecure, I wouldn't recommend it. However, you could set up an SSH server using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) that would allow you to remotely connect to a Windows 7 computer via SSH (Secure Shell). Lifehacker has a [fairly straightforward guide](http://lifehacker.com/205090/geek-to-live--set-up-a-personal-home-ssh-server) on just that.

Comment: I highly recommend OpenSSH for Windows. Telnet is NOT the way to go as it is very insecure as you pointed out, SSH uses encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Windows remote management and remote shell are built-in:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(v=vs.85).aspx